# Jspeex encoding error

Tags: java

I am getting error "java.lang.nullpointerexception"
in the code

```
 public int getProcessedData(final byte[] data, final int offset)
  {
    int size = bits.getBufferSize();
   System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(), 0, data, offset, size);
    bits.init();
    return size;
  }
```

Comment: either *bits* or *data* is null.

Comment: TheLostMind is correct - and we can't know which is null unless you send us more code or a better stack trace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: public int getProcessedData(final byte[] data, final int offset)
  {
    int size = bits.getBuffeSize();
   System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset, size);
    bits.init();
    return size;
  }

  
  public int getProcessedDataByteSize()
  {
    return bits.getBufferSize();
  } getting null pointer exception in line no.4

Answer (score 0):

Assign the values for **bits/data**

```
Null pointer exception appears when you declare a variable but did not create an 
object. If you attempt to dereference num BEFORE creating the object you get a 
NullPointerException.
```

**Keep debugging the code, then you can easily find where the exception occurs.**

Comment: public int getProcessedData(final byte[] data, final int offset) { int size = bits.getBuffeSize(); System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset, size); bits.init(); return size; } public int getProcessedDataByteSize() { return bits.getBufferSize(); } getting null pointer exception in line no.4 –

Comment: getting null  pointer exception in:  System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset, size);